# How to calculate total hour minus spend time php

Tags: php, time

i have total hours and timeSpend

```
$totalHours=30;
$timeSpend=13:22:00
```

how can i find remaining time

```
$totalHours-$timeSpend
```

result should be like 16:38:00

if `timeSpend> $total` hours  return minus value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert all the values to seconds. So you can convert your time spend using this

```
$str_time = "2:50";

sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

$timeSeconds = isset($seconds) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $hours * 60 + $minutes;
```

Then you can convert hours to seconds by multiplying by 3600

```
$totalSeconds = $totalHours * 3600;
```

Then you can substract one from the other to get remaining seconds.

```
$remainingSeconds = $totalSeconds - $timeSeconds;
```

Then format it back to a time

```
$timeText = gmdate("H:i:s", remainingSeconds );
```

Comment: thanks. this works, but in case timeSpend is larger than total hours, it fails i$totalHours=30;
$timeSpend=31:22:00 ineed answer -01:22:00

Comment: You should test to see if the remainingSeconds is < 0 before you change the format back to time.

Answer (score 2):

You could try any one of the Approaches. Approach NR. 1 is a lot straight-forward, though a little more verbose:

**APPROACH NR. 1**

```
<?php
    $totalHours = 16;
    $timeSpend  = "13:22:00";
    $baseDate   = "2016-05-11";
    $result     = null;
    $dateDiff   = null;

    // CONVERT BOTH $totalHours AND $timeSpend TO DATETIME OBJECTS USING AN ARBITRARY DATE AS BASE:::
    // HERE WE USED THE DATE: 2016-05-11 BUT YOU CAN USE ANY DATE.
    $date1      = new DateTime($baseDate);
    $date2      = new DateTime($baseDate . " " . $timeSpend );

    //ADD 30 HOUR TO $date1
    $date1->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $totalHours . "H"));

    //FIND THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THE 2.
    $dateDiff   = date_diff($date2, $date1);

    // IF $date1 IS GREATER THAN $date2; SIMPLY ASSIGN THE DATE DIFFERENCE TO $dateDiff
    // ELSE ASSIGN NULL TO $dateDiff
    if( ($date1 > $date2) ){
        $dateDiff   = date_diff($date2, $date1);

        //NOW FINALLY GET THE HOURS, MINUTES & SECONDS FROM THE RESULT
        $hour       = ($dateDiff->h < 10)? "0".$dateDiff->h : $dateDiff->h;
        $min        = ($dateDiff->i < 10)? "0".$dateDiff->i : $dateDiff->i;
        $sec        = ($dateDiff->s < 10)? "0".$dateDiff->s : $dateDiff->s;
        $result     = $hour . ":" . $min . ":" . $sec;
    }else{
        $dateDiff   = null;
    }

    //TEST YOUR RESULT...
    var_dump($result);      //DUMPS '16:38:00' TO THE OUTPUT STREAM...
```

**APPROACH NR. 2**

```
    <?php
        $totalHours = 30;
        $timeSpend  = "13:22:00";

        // CONVERT BOTH $totalHours & $timeSpend TO UNIX TIMESTAMP.
        $time1      = $totalHours * 60* 60;
        $time2      = strtotime($timeSpend);

        // CHECK IF $totalHours IS GREATER THAN $timeSpent
        // IF IT IS; SUBTRACT $timeSpent FROM $totalHours
        // AND ASSIGN THE DIFFERENCE TO $diff
        // OTHERWISE ASSIGN NULL TO $diff 
        $diff       = ($time1 > $time2) ? ($time1 - $time2) :null;

        // NOW REFORMAT DIFF USING PHP'S date FORMATTING FUNCTION:
        $diffTime   = date("H:i:s", $diff); 

        // JUST DO SOME TESTS TO SEE YOUR RESULT DUMPED TO THE OUTPUT STREAM:
        var_dump($diffTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can minus timespend from totalhours
example.

```
$remaining = $totalhours - $timespend;
echo $remaining;
```